# Is the GitHub traffic insight reliable?

Tags: github

I have a [repo](https://github.com/BrainStormYourWayIn/sierra) that was public initially, made private later, and turned public again only a while ago.

My issue is, I had about 250 views with only 2 unique viewers before it turned private (I don't know how THAT's possible).

Once I had made it public, I checked the traffic and had 727 views with still only 2 unique viewers, and the graph even shows a view count when the repo went private for a few days.

How did the view count jump so high and how did my repo have views even when it was private?

Any form of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes, the numbers include everyone's views including repository owners and contributors. There's no way to filter this information at the moment but we can definitely add that as a feature request for the team to consider. Your own views are counted on repository traffic graphs, and there is no way to filter out your own page views of those of other repository contributors**

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that answer, it's outdated and the information is also filtered now